# How to plot 4 columns vs time

Tags: r

So I have data that looks like this.
One data point per second.

I need to be able to have a scatter plot, for each day of the last 4 columns (standing, stepping, cycling, New_sitting) vs Time. Basically if the data set spans for 5 days, I need 5 plots. The program needs to be able to know that.
I'll also be mutating the last 4 column data so that instead of all 1s they can be 1,2,3,4 and so the scatter plot will show an "up down" function of change over time.

```
> head(pre,100)
          Date                Time Axis1 Axis2 Axis3     VM Standing Stepping Cycling New_Sitting
1   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:00    89    41    39 105.47        0        0       1           0
2   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:01    88   135   117 199.14        0        1       0           0
3   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:02     0    61     8  61.52        0        0       1           0
4   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:03     0    25     0  25.00        0        0       0           1
5   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:04     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
6   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:05     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
7   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:06     0    24    35  42.44        0        1       0           0
8   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:07     0    28     0  28.00        1        0       0           0
9   2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:08     4    96    20  98.14        1        0       0           0
10  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:09     0    11     0  11.00        1        0       0           0
11  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:10     3    91    22  93.67        1        0       0           0
12  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:11     9    44     2  44.96        1        0       0           0
13  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:12     5     8    16  18.57        1        0       0           0
14  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:13     0     8    21  22.47        1        0       0           0
15  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:14     1    29    48  56.09        0        1       0           0
16  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:15     0     1     3   3.16        1        0       0           0
17  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:16     0    17    35  38.91        0        1       0           0
18  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:17     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
19  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:18     0     0     5   5.00        1        0       0           0
20  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:19     0     0    29  29.00        0        1       0           0
21  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:20     0    15    32  35.34        0        1       0           0
22  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:21     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
23  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:22     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
24  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:23     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
25  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:24     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
26  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:25     0    28     4  28.28        1        0       0           0
27  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:26    13    47    26  55.26        0        1       0           0
28  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:27    11    28    68  74.36        0        1       0           0
29  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:28     3    48     5  48.35        1        0       0           0
30  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:29     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
31  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:30     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
32  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:31     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
33  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:32     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
34  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:33     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
35  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:34     7    44    20  48.84        1        0       0           0
36  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:35    10    46    39  61.13        0        1       0           0
37  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:36     1    13    63  64.34        0        1       0           0
38  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:37     0     0    11  11.00        1        0       0           0
39  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:38     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
40  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:39     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
41  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:40     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
42  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:41     0    22    24  32.56        1        0       0           0
43  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:42     0    19    21  28.32        1        0       0           0
44  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:43     0     6    17  18.03        1        0       0           0
45  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:44     0     6     0   6.00        1        0       0           0
46  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:45     0    14    46  48.08        0        1       0           0
47  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:46     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
48  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:47     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
49  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:48     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
50  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:49     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
51  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:50     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
52  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:51     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
53  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:52     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
54  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:53     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
55  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:54     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
56  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:55     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
57  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:56     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
58  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:57     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
59  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:58     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
60  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:51:59     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
61  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:00     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
62  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:01     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
63  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:02     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
64  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:03     5     0     6   7.81        1        0       0           0
65  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:04     5     0    64  64.20        0        1       0           0
66  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:05    10    34    62  71.41        0        1       0           0
67  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:06     1     0     0   1.00        1        0       0           0
68  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:07    14    41    69  81.47        0        1       0           0
69  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:08     0    52    40  65.60        0        1       0           0
70  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:09     0    25    46  52.35        0        1       0           0
71  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:10     9    24    41  48.35        0        1       0           0
72  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:11     0     7    37  37.66        0        1       0           0
73  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:12     0     0     0   0.00        1        0       0           0
74  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:13    18    15    57  61.63        0        1       0           0
75  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:14    13    18    86  88.82        0        1       0           0
76  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:15     0    34    47  58.01        0        1       0           0
77  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:16     0     6     1   6.08        1        0       0           0
78  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:17     0    27    61  66.71        0        1       0           0
79  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:18     0    21     5  21.59        1        0       0           0
80  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:19    22    53    62  84.48        0        1       0           0
81  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:20     6    56    12  57.58        1        0       0           0
82  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:21    13    10     8  18.25        1        0       0           0
83  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:22    65    70   120 153.38        0        1       0           0
84  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:23    29    24    47  60.22        0        1       0           0
85  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:24     8     7    43  44.29        0        1       0           0
86  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:25    28    10    90  94.78        0        1       0           0
87  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:26    31    50    65  87.67        0        1       0           0
88  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:27    12    81    53  97.54        0        1       0           0
89  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:28    16    59    33  69.47        0        1       0           0
90  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:29   148    12    99 178.46        0        0       1           0
91  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:30    75     2    60  96.07        0        0       1           0
92  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:31    79     0    23  82.28        0        0       1           0
93  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:32    16     0     0  16.00        0        0       0           1
94  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:33     7     0     0   7.00        0        0       0           1
95  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:34     6     0     0   6.00        0        0       0           1
96  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:35     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
97  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:36     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
98  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:37     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
99  2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:38     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
100 2022-03-14 2022-03-14 09:52:39     0     0     0   0.00        0        0       0           1
```

PS
Currently using this code to sum all columns by date, might be useful?

```
Summary_PRE <- workday_PRE %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) %>% summarise(across(Axis1:Counter,sum))
Summary_PRE <- subset (Summary_PRE, select = -c(Axis1,Axis2,Axis3,VM))
```

EDIT

```
> dput(head(pre,100))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 
19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065, 19065), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(1647265860, 
1647265861, 1647265862, 1647265863, 1647265864, 1647265865, 1647265866, 
1647265867, 1647265868, 1647265869, 1647265870, 1647265871, 1647265872, 
1647265873, 1647265874, 1647265875, 1647265876, 1647265877, 1647265878, 
1647265879, 1647265880, 1647265881, 1647265882, 1647265883, 1647265884, 
1647265885, 1647265886, 1647265887, 1647265888, 1647265889, 1647265890, 
1647265891, 1647265892, 1647265893, 1647265894, 1647265895, 1647265896, 
1647265897, 1647265898, 1647265899, 1647265900, 1647265901, 1647265902, 
1647265903, 1647265904, 1647265905, 1647265906, 1647265907, 1647265908, 
1647265909, 1647265910, 1647265911, 1647265912, 1647265913, 1647265914, 
1647265915, 1647265916, 1647265917, 1647265918, 1647265919, 1647265920, 
1647265921, 1647265922, 1647265923, 1647265924, 1647265925, 1647265926, 
1647265927, 1647265928, 1647265929, 1647265930, 1647265931, 1647265932, 
1647265933, 1647265934, 1647265935, 1647265936, 1647265937, 1647265938, 
1647265939, 1647265940, 1647265941, 1647265942, 1647265943, 1647265944, 
1647265945, 1647265946, 1647265947, 1647265948, 1647265949, 1647265950, 
1647265951, 1647265952, 1647265953, 1647265954, 1647265955, 1647265956, 
1647265957, 1647265958, 1647265959), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Axis1 = c(89, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 
9, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 11, 3, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 7, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 10, 1, 14, 0, 0, 9, 
0, 0, 18, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 6, 13, 65, 29, 8, 28, 31, 12, 16, 
148, 75, 79, 16, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Axis2 = c(41, 135, 61, 
25, 0, 0, 24, 28, 96, 11, 91, 44, 8, 8, 29, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0, 15, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 47, 28, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 46, 13, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 22, 19, 6, 6, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 41, 52, 25, 24, 7, 0, 15, 18, 34, 6, 
27, 21, 53, 56, 10, 70, 24, 7, 10, 50, 81, 59, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Axis3 = c(39, 117, 8, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 20, 
0, 22, 2, 16, 21, 48, 3, 35, 0, 5, 29, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 26, 
68, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 39, 63, 11, 0, 0, 0, 24, 21, 17, 0, 
46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 64, 
62, 0, 69, 40, 46, 41, 37, 0, 57, 86, 47, 1, 61, 5, 62, 12, 8, 
120, 47, 43, 90, 65, 53, 33, 99, 60, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), VM = c(105.47, 199.14, 61.52, 25, 0, 0, 42.44, 28, 98.14, 
11, 93.67, 44.96, 18.57, 22.47, 56.09, 3.16, 38.91, 0, 5, 29, 
35.34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28.28, 55.26, 74.36, 48.35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
48.84, 61.13, 64.34, 11, 0, 0, 0, 32.56, 28.32, 18.03, 6, 48.08, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.81, 64.2, 
71.41, 1, 81.47, 65.6, 52.35, 48.35, 37.66, 0, 61.63, 88.82, 
58.01, 6.08, 66.71, 21.59, 84.48, 57.58, 18.25, 153.38, 60.22, 
44.29, 94.78, 87.67, 97.54, 69.47, 178.46, 96.07, 82.28, 16, 
7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Standing = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Stepping = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Cycling = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), New_Sitting = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share the example data in an unambiguous way that is possible for others to load directly. The easiest way is often to use the magical `dput` function to make a code recipe for your data, in this case `dput(head(pre,100))`, and then paste the output into the body of your question.

Comment: If you want to plot multiple variables in ggplot, and they have the same units, it's typical to rely on the `tidyr::pivot_longer()` function to reshape the data so that the last four columns are converted into two columns, the first specifying which action, the second describing the number. Then each of these can be mapped in ggplot2 to an aesthetic, such as color or facet for the action, and y for the number.

Comment: I've added the ```dput(head(pre,100))``` data, not sure what that did since I haven't had any issues with people reading my  data so far. Second, not sure how this groups and gives me a plot by date?

Comment: Thanks for adding the `dput` output. It's quicker for people to load, and more importantly it makes it so the data types we're working with match yours. That can be very useful when working with dates, factors, integers vs. doubles, grouped data, nested data, etc. So it's not strictly necessary for simple tables, but it never hurts to be specific when it comes to programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that by "instead of all 1s they can be 1,2,3,4" you mean that you want to convert the individual detections into some sort of metric that captures the frequency over time. I arbitrarily summed the detections over a rolling 1 minute time frame (you could use something like `lubridate::seconds(10)` if you wanted a smaller time window). Then I pivot_longer to bring those four columns into a matched pair of "name" (of the orig column) and "value" (from the orig column), and plot those. Note that I am faceting by Date, but giving each facet a free x axis scale, so that in multi-day data you should see an x axis that matches the range for that day.

```
pre %>%
  # change columns 7-10 to sum over a 1 minute rolling period
  mutate(across(7:10, ~slider::slide_index_dbl(., Time, sum, 
                       .before = lubridate::minutes(1)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(7:10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Date, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]